# call src in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, src

I am trying to have a widget work but I need to call my src after the page loads so that my functions have time to run and right now I am having problems I can't get it to work. All I need is to be able to call the src after the function is completed. I've attached my code, sorry is so messy this is my first time coding.

```
<script>
  var hi = "3911 e Douglas loop"
  var src1 
  function init() {
    window.onmessage = (event) => {
      hi = event.data;
      src1 = "//www.narrpr.com/widgets/avm-widget/widget.ashx/script"
      injectScript("//www.narrpr.com/widgets/avm-widget/widget.ashx/script")
    }
  }

  var rprAvmWidgetOptions = {
    Token: "742980EF-52EE-46F2-AEFB",
    Query: hi,
    CoBrandCode: "btso48",
    ShowRprLinks: false
  }

  function injectScript(src) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.async = true;
      script.src = src;
      script.addEventListener('load', resolve);
      script.addEventListener('error', () => reject('Error loading script.'));
      script.addEventListener('abort', () => reject('Script loading 
 aborted.'));
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    });
  }
</script>
<script src = src1 > </script>
<body onload="init();" style="background-color:transpartnt;">
```

This is all the code I actually need to have it work except, it doesn't because the src lodes too fast so my function cant run and grab the global var and assign it to the rprAvmWidgetOptions var.

```
 <head>
 <script>
 var hi = "3919 e douglas loop"
  function init() {
    window.onmessage = (event) => {
      hi = event.data;
    }
  }

  var rprAvmWidgetOptions = {
    Token: "742980EF-52EE-46F2-AEFB",
    Query: hi,
    CoBrandCode: "btso48",
    ShowRprLinks: false
  }
</script>
</head>

<script src = "//www.narrpr.com/widgets/avm-widget/widget.ashx/script" > 
</script>
<body onload="init();" style="background-color:transpartnt;">
```

So I need to load the src later and then my function will have assigned the "hi" var and everything will work. so I need some kind of delay. It would be perfect if I could just call the src from inside the HTML.

Comment: Hi @noah-fennema, can you describe what you're expecting this function to do?

Comment: My function is grabbing a global string with the function       init() {
window.onmessage = (event) => {

and then plugs that var into an src that returns a iframe with a bunch of info. the injectScript(src) function  was my best bet at trying to "post load" the src

Comment: Note that your script src should point to a string, in quotation marks.

Comment: Try changing this line: `<script src = //www.narrpr.com/widgets/avm-widget/widget.ashx/script >`, to this: `<script src="www.narrpr.com/widgets/avm-widget/widget.ashx/script"> `

Comment: got it. still doesn't work tho :/

Comment: ..you are missing alot of semicolons in your code..

Answer (score 0):

Have you placed the `script` in the `head` ? It is preferable to put it at the end of the body, so that it allows the HTML elements to load first, then execute the script.

Comment: so I went through and put the code in the head and it still doesn't load fast enough. here is my console log when i ran it. 

          
AVM WIDGET: Loading jQuery...

script:2 AVM WIDGET: Status [0] > Successfully loaded

script:2 AVM WIDGET: Loading Google Analytics API...

script:2 AVM WIDGET: Checking for GA... ƒ (a){J(1);Z.D.apply(Z [arguments])}

console.js:35 5539 East Baseline Road, Gilbert, AZ, USA

so the widget is loading faster than my code can output the global var (5539 East Baseline Road, Gilbert, AZ, USA)

Comment: No I meant to put the code at the end of the body tag, so it allows the html elements to load first then to load the script. And to be honest I have no clue why would you need it to load anymore faster when it should already load it in less than 50-100ms which is still fast. Try putting the code at the END of the body in a <script></script>

Comment: I updated the second code sample at the top. so you mean replace the head tags with body tags?

Comment: and I just need my function to load faster than the src so I can inject my vars into the rprAvmWidgetOptions

Comment: Sorry man, you totally lost me what you want to achieve and as far as I can say, I'm not the only one confused by what you want to do. This should load the script when the body is loaded, and set its source to that one.

Comment: I tried that and i got a "Uncaught ReferenceError: script is not defined" error.

Answer (score -1):

It may be helpful to try running your code in a snippet.

You can make a snippet on StackOverFlow by clicking on the <> icon.

For example, here is a simple snippet of HTML and JavaScript:

```js
console.log('hello, javascript')
```

```html
<div>
Hello, HTML
<div>
```

Note that your HTML  src should point to a string, in quotation marks.

Comment: My code is not going to work in this environment the src requires a specified domain as well as my token to work so the snippet wont work